# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_options` error?

Tags: database

I am trying to manually restore my WordPress site which has been backed up using Updraft plus plugin. I uploaded & extracted all the files to their respective folder. However, when I tried to upload database via PhpMyAdmin I got following error.
[image: Error image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Click on *Databases* at the top and select the database. If the database no longer exists, create a new one under the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not select the database in which you want to execute your query.

Please execute following query first to select your database:

`use database_name`

Or else in your query add database name before table name like

`drop table if exists databasename.tablename`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/creating-database.html).
If you don't have the database create instruction inside your script:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_db;
```

You need to manually do that.

Else if you have the database:

use this to select it first before executing the script.

```
USE your_db;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be inside a database before importing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

simple answer,  open with your favorite editor the .sql backup file, and with ctrl+F find that line, comment it out or delete it and try again, that error will no longer exist